# Types as theories

Tags: semantics, denotational-semantics

I am studying Goguen's paper Types as theories [1].
Based on Goguen's paper, are the following true?

1. Subsort inheritance provides a classification of values, every value of the sub-sort is a value of the super-sort.
2. Module import inheritance provides classification of models, each model of the class of models of the importing module contains a model of the imported module.

Below are two example coded in CafeOBJ (any other algebraic specification language would do).

Assumptions

1. the module is the software realization of a theory
2. loose semantics
3. normal protecting mode for import
4. the term type is synonym for sort
5. the < symbol indicates subsort

---

```
mod* SUBSORT { 
[  Group < Elt ]
-- Signature in terms of super type
op e : -> Elt 
op _._ : Elt Elt -> Elt 
-- equations in terms of subtype
vars A B C : Group 
eq A . e = A . 
eq e . A = A . 
eq A . (B . C) = ((A . B) . C) .
 }


mod* MONOID {
-- The TRIV theory represented by the CafeOBJ 
-- built in module TRIV which has Elt as its principal sort
protecting(TRIV)
op e : -> Elt 
op _._ : Elt Elt -> Elt 
vars A B C : Elt 
eq A . e = A . 
eq e . A = A . 
eq A . (B . C) = ((A . B) . C) .
}
```

Regards,
Pat

[1]Goguen, J. (1991). Types as Theories. Topology and Category in Computer
Science. G. M. Reed, A. W. Roscoe and R. F. Wachter, Oxford University
Press: 357-390.
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.16.2241